# How to count how many rows with some value are a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I am interested in Libre Office Calc, but it's perhaps similar or even identical as in Excel.

So, let's say I want to know how many cells in the column A have something in them.

How to count how many rows with some value are in the column A?

And I would like to display the result (number of cells/rows with somthing in them) in a B1 cell.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count is the way to go, theres a few versions, either

```
=countif(a:a,"value to count")
```

place what you want to count between "" unless its a number then dont use the ""

or

```
=counta(a:a)
```

will count anything with something in (includes text and numbers)

or

```
=count(a:a)
```

where only counts numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=countif(a:a, "something")
```